# Are phase angles in filter transfer functions primarily for stability?

Tags: filter, transfer-function, phase, bode-plot

I see transfer functions and bode plots (magnitude and phase) and it occurred to me, that I don't really use the phase plots at all. My career experience seems to have gotten away without having to use or calculate them except once where I had a stability issue with an opamp. But this just shows a gap in my experience / knowledge that I would like to resolve before I genuinely need it.

When we look at general filter topologies that show phase plots, why is that relevent to show. For instance, a single order LPF will have a phase shift of -45 deg @ fc - so what ? Why do we care about these numbers in filters ? Is it that when we cascade them, it becomes relevant when looking at phase margin ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different applications are sensitive to phase variation with frequency for different reasons.

- It can impact stability margin if the filter is in a closed-loop system.
- The total error between a source signal and a filtered signal is a function of phase (as an extreme example, if h(x) defines a filter with a gain of 1 and a phase shift of 180 degrees at some frequency, then at that frequency the error signal y = x - h(x) will have an amplitude twice that of x).
- If the phase does not change linearly with frequency then the group delay of the filter won't be constant.  This will causes pulses to be smeared out, which is a Bad Thing in communications systems.
- If the group delay of a filter is high it will contribute to the overall delay in a communications system.  This is much less likely to be a problem, but can still be an issue in some applications.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we care about these numbers in filters ?

If we built a low pass filter (of some filter order) that had a cut off frequency of (say) 1 kHz, we might expect it to pass a complex signal that had an upper limit of spectral content of (say) 200 Hz fairly unhindered.

This would largely happen if the filter introduced (say) 1 degree of phase shift at 100 Hz and 2 degrees at 200 Hz because the introduced time delays of those parts of the spectrum would be equal. However, if the filter was poorly designed it might be 1 degree at 100 Hz and possibly 4 degrees at 200 Hz. This would lead to an output signal with a less optimum shape. Of course one man’s meat is another man’s poison and a different target application for a filter might benefit from this effect.

Without knowing the phase change for each part of the spectrum means we cannot know what a complex output signal will look like in detail.

Of course, as you have already established, putting a filter inside a negative feedback loop can lead to unwanted oscillation of the loop and so analysis of the phase change requires us to know that part of the bode plot.